# Help me understand variance in a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

In my notes I see that if we had n random variables (let's say they are $X_i,...,X_n$), and we knew they were IID (independent and identically distributed), and we say they are all Normally distributed, then we say that the variance of the AVERAGE of these variables is Variance = $\sigma^2/n$. I would like a better understanding of what "n" is. Is "n" the SAMPLE SIZE, or is it the NUMBER OF SAMPLES?

I feel like it must be the latter, because if "n" represented the number of samples I took, I could take a billion samples and then divide my variance by a billion and say hey look, there's no variance at all in the average of these variables! But clearly that can't be true, just because I took lots of samples, that shouldn't affect the average variance of all of them, and I assume they all have some normal-looking variance.

Furthermore, how many values can an $X_i$ take? Can I say that, for example, $X_4$ takes on values of 40, 50, 51, and 52, knowing that $X_4$ is normally distributed with, say, $\mu=45$ and $\sigma = 8$? I'm just making up numbers obviously, but is it valid to say that a single random variable can actually have several different values? Or can $X_i$ only be one number and that's it?

Comment: It’s the sample size. I believe the precise definition of a “sample” is a list of independent and identically distributed random variables (someone correct me if I’m wrong). So, there’s only one sample here. The items in the sample should not be called “samples”.

Comment: $X_i$ is a random variable. The value of $X_i$ depends on the outcome of our random experiment. If $X_i$ is normally distributed, then there are infinitely many possible values of $X_i$, depending on the outcome of our random experiment.

Comment: @littleO - does that then mean $X_i$ IS this "list of independent and identically distributed random variables"? Like $X_4$ is 40, 50, 51, 52?

Comment: No, $X_4$ is one of the random variables in the list of random variables. So the list of random variables is $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.